# Illegal string offset while processing json decode array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am getting following output when i use json_decode for api response

```
Array
(
    [Description] => {
  "CustomerData": [
    {

      "CustomerId": "XXXXX290",
      "MemExpiryDate": "2301",      
      "MobileNo": "XXXXXXX833",      

    },
    {

      "CustomerId": "XXXXX291",
      "MemExpiryDate": "2109",     
      "MobileNo": "XXXXXXX587", 


    }
  ]
}
)
```

When i am trying to get CustomerId value with

```
echo $resp['Description']['CustomerData'][0][CustomerId]
```

i am getting error

```
   Warning: Illegal string offset 'CustomerData'
```

can any one explain me how to get value of CustomerId and what am i doing wrong ?

Original response before using json_decode

```
{"Description":"{\r\n \"CustomerData\": [\r\n {\r\n \"CustomerId\": \"XXXXX290\",\r\n \"MemExpiryDate\": \"2301\",\r\n \"MobileNo\": \"XXXXXXX833\"},\r\n {\r\n \"CustomerId\": \"XXXXX291\",\r\n \"MemExpiryDate\": \"2109\",\r\n \"MobileNo\": \"XXXXXXX587\" }\r\n ]\r\n}"}
```

Comment: Can you show your original JSON as it looks like `Description` is a JSON string.

Comment: Maybe you should use json_decode with second $assoc true param.

Comment: @NigelRen, i have edited my question, have added response before json_decode

Comment: @AaronYordanyan i don't get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Description` element of `$resp` is also a JSON string.  You need to decode this to be able to access the data you are after...

```
$description = json_decode($resp['Description'], true);

echo $description['CustomerData'][0]['CustomerId'];
```